# How do I hide the controls loading process in Excel, USING C#?

Tags: c#, excel, hide, controls, loading

I used  app.ScreenUpdating to hide the loading process in Excel.

It does not show the loading process anymore except, it still shows loading the controls(combo-box,datepicker,buttons).

Does anyone know some way to not show loading the controls?

Thanks!

Comment: You could turn their display off temporarily:  ActiveWorkbook.DisplayDrawingObjects = xlPlaceholders

Comment: @jkpieterse Thanks, but it still shows, I think I will just use app.Visible = false;